# Installing gocql error

Tags: go, cassandra

Hello folks I'm trying to '$ go get github.com/gocql/gocql' to install on a Ubuntu AWS box. Any advice at all much appreciated.

I'm logging in as ubuntu@some.ip.adre.ss

general file structure is

```
/home/ubuntu
/home/ubuntu/go
/home/ubuntu/cassandra
```

-

```
$ go get github.com/gocql/gocql
# github.com/gocql/gocql
src/github.com/gocql/gocql/conn.go:137:19: error: reference to undefined identifier ‘tls.DialWithDialer’
   conn, err = tls.DialWithDialer(dialer, "tcp", addr, cfg.tlsConfig)
               ^
src/github.com/gocql/gocql/frame.go:242:23: error: reference to undefined identifier ‘sync.Pool’
 var framerPool = sync.Pool{
                   ^
src/github.com/gocql/gocql/frame.go:242:27: error: expected ‘;’ or newline after top level declaration
 var framerPool = sync.Pool{
                       ^
src/github.com/gocql/gocql/frame.go:248:2: error: expected declaration
  },
  ^
```

My golang setup is...

```
$ go env
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN=""
GOCHAR="6"
GOEXE=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="linux"
GOOS="linux"
GOPATH="/home/ubuntu/go"
GORACE=""
GOROOT="/usr"
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/pkg/tool/linux_amd64"
TERM="dumb"
CC="gcc"
GOGCCFLAGS="-g -O2 -fPIC -m64 -pthread"
CXX="g++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
```

My Java details are:

```
$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_51"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_51-b16)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.51-b03, mixed mode)
```

Cassandra:

```
home/ubuntu/cassandra/bin$ ./cqlsh
Connected to Test Cluster at localhost:9160.
[cqlsh 4.1.1 | Cassandra 2.0.16 | CQL spec 3.1.1 | Thrift protocol 19.39.0]
Use HELP for help.
cqlsh>
```

Comment: I would have said that the package is broken, but I successfully installed it right now on my machine. Try to do a `go get -u` in case it really was broken and got fixed in the meantime.

Comment: Figured out the problem... I was using an old version of Go. I feel stupid :(

Comment: Happens to us all one time or another...

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the problem... I was using an old version of Go. I feel stupid :( –